# Find a surjective function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a surjective function $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{Q}$;

I know that at least one such function must exist since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, but I haven't been able to find one.

Can someone show me one such function?

Best regards,

lorenzo

Comment: hint: find a surjective $\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For any positive integers $a$ and $b$, let $f(2^a3^b)=\frac{a}{b}$ and let $f(2^a5^b)=-\frac{a}{b}$. For any other natural number $n$, let $f(n)=0$.

Comment: To the OP: It is important to note that $2,3,5$ are primes. Such a method would not work if they were not. This follows from the uniqueness of prime decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

Make a grid in the upper right quadrant, and at location $(i, j)$ put the rational number $(i/j)$.

Now traverse the grid along diagonal lines where $i + j = c$, i.e. in the order

```
1/1
2/1  1/2
3/1  2/2 1/3
4/1  3/2  2/3  1/4
...
```

Eventually you will hit every number $i/j$ (in particular, it'll be in the $k$th row, where $k = i + j$.

This gives a surjective map $f$ from $\mathbb N$ to the positive rationals.

Now: split $\mathbb N$ into three groups: $0$, positive evens, and positive odds.

Send $0$ to $0$. Send $2n$ to $f(n)$. And send $2n+1$ to $-f(n)$. That defines your surjective function.

Comment: This gives you only the positive rationals, but it's easy to modify.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks, Robert!

Comment: @JohnHughes : Thank you for your answer; I've been trying to come up with a formula for the function $f$ as you've described it, but without success; can you give me an hint about this?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** First try to think about a surjective function $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}^{2}$, and then think about a surjective function $\mathbb{N}^{2}\to\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ by recalling that a positive rational number is of the form $\frac{p}{q}$ with $p,q\in\mathbb{N}$. Then finally, take a surjective function $\mathbb{Q}^{+}\to\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

The elements of $\mathbb Q$ are quotients of two integers, so a injection can be established between $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z ^2$. Then traversing the elements of the two dimensional array $\mathbb Z ^2$ with a spiral suffices.